# Simplify the oracle query without UNION

Tags: sql, oracle, union

Is it possible to avoid UNION in this query? I dont have enough knowledge to simplify this query. Can anyone help on this query? Thanks in advance

```
SELECT A.M_TITLE, A.M_NUMBER, B.M_NAME, B.M_DESCRIPTION, A.FORM_TYPE, B.SUBMISSION_DATE, B.CREATON_DATE, A.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORM_ID,
B.R_OBJECT_ID AS
FORMDATA_ID, '' AS ATTACHMENTS 
FROM M_FORM A, M_FORMDATA B 
WHERE A.M_NUMBER = B.M_NUMBER 
AND ANY B.ATTACHMENTS IN (SELECT ATTACHMENTS FROM M_FORMDATA C WHERE B.M_NUMBER = C.M_NUMBER) 
AND ACTION_ID = 'XXXX' 
AND SUBMISSION_DATE >= DATE('XXXX') 
AND SUBMISSION_DATE <= DATE('XXXX') 

UNION 

SELECT A.M_TITLE, A.M_NUMBER, B.M_NAME, B.M_DESCRIPTION, A.FORM_TYPE, B.SUBMISSION_DATE, B.CREATION_DATE, A.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORM_ID,
B.R_OBJECT_ID AS
FORMDATA_ID, 'null' AS ATTACHMENTS 
FROM M_FORM A, M_FORMDATA 
WHERE A.M_NUMBER = B.M_NUMBER 
AND NOT ANY B.ATTACHMENTS IN (SELECT ATTACHMENTS FROM M_FORMDATA C WHERE B.M_NUMBER = C.M_NUMBER) 
AND ACTION_ID= 'XXXX' 
AND SUBMISSION_DATE >= DATE('XXXX') 
AND SUBMISSION_DATE <= DATE('XXXX')
```

Comment: First thing you should do, is to properly format and indent your query.

Comment: Does it make any sense to use `any` in one query and `not any` in another statement for the same set of where conditions and then using union? I think removing `B.ATTACHMENTS IN (SELECT ATTACHMENTS FROM M_FORMDATA C WHERE B.M_NUMBER = C.M_NUMBER) ` from both the queries and using one query only will suffice.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct. this query has written by someone. i try to simplify. because same query using in both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, here is the same query reformatted a bit to see what it actually does:

```
SELECT A.M_TITLE,
  A.M_NUMBER,
  B.M_NAME,
  B.M_DESCRIPTION,
  A.FORM_TYPE,
  B.SUBMISSION_DATE,
  B.CREATON_DATE,
  A.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORM_ID,
  B.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORMDATA_ID,
  ''            AS ATTACHMENTS
FROM M_FORM A,
  M_FORMDATA B
WHERE A.M_NUMBER       = B.M_NUMBER
AND ANY B.ATTACHMENTS IN
  (SELECT ATTACHMENTS FROM M_FORMDATA C WHERE B.M_NUMBER = C.M_NUMBER)
AND ACTION_ID        = 'XXXX'
AND SUBMISSION_DATE >= DATE('XXXX')
AND SUBMISSION_DATE <= DATE('XXXX')
UNION
SELECT A.M_TITLE,
  A.M_NUMBER,
  B.M_NAME,
  B.M_DESCRIPTION,
  A.FORM_TYPE,
  B.SUBMISSION_DATE,
  B.CREATION_DATE,
  A.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORM_ID,
  B.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORMDATA_ID,
  ''            AS ATTACHMENTS
FROM M_FORM A,
  M_FORMDATA
WHERE A.M_NUMBER           = B.M_NUMBER
AND NOT ANY B.ATTACHMENTS IN
  (SELECT ATTACHMENTS FROM M_FORMDATA C WHERE B.M_NUMBER = C.M_NUMBER
  )
AND ACTION_ID        = 'XXXX'
AND SUBMISSION_DATE >= DATE('XXXX')
AND SUBMISSION_DATE <= DATE('XXXX')
```

My first question is, does this query actually run? My SQL Developer tells me that there is a syntax error near the two ANY statements. You may have to rewrite the query to use something like `[..] AND B.ATTACHMENTS = ANY (...) [..]`.

Second, if you can, always use `UNION ALL`. A simple `UNION` has to sort the results to remove any duplicates which can be relatively slow. So if possible, use the `UNION ALL`.

Lastly, I have no idea what this query does but it seems that there are two queries and the only difference is in the attachments predicates. In the query above you query if the attachment is in the subquery, in the second you check if the attachment is NOT in the subquery. Why not just remove this predicate then? Check if the following query returns the same results:

```
SELECT A.M_TITLE,
  A.M_NUMBER,
  B.M_NAME,
  B.M_DESCRIPTION,
  A.FORM_TYPE,
  B.SUBMISSION_DATE,
  B.CREATON_DATE,
  A.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORM_ID,
  B.R_OBJECT_ID AS FORMDATA_ID,
  ''            AS ATTACHMENTS
FROM M_FORM A,
  M_FORMDATA B
WHERE A.M_NUMBER       = B.M_NUMBER
AND ACTION_ID        = 'XXXX'
AND SUBMISSION_DATE >= DATE('XXXX')
AND SUBMISSION_DATE <= DATE('XXXX');
```

Comment: I was editing my query. But efore you complete the formatting and answered my question. This query is running in my application. Thank you so much.